# Calculate cosh 1 correct to 6 decimal places.

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Calculate $\cosh 1$ correct to 6 decimal places.

Comment: Are you supposed to use Taylor series? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried using the Taylor series?

Answer (score 7):

Notice $$\cosh x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
We have:
$$\begin{align} &\left|\;\cosh 1 - \left(1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \frac{1}{6!} + \frac{1}{8!}\right)\right|\\
= & \frac{1}{10!}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{11\cdot 12} + \frac{1}{11\cdot 12 \cdot 13 \cdot 14} + \cdots\right)\\
\le &\frac{1}{10!}\left(1 + 10^{-2} + 10^{-4} + \cdots\right)\\
= &\frac{100}{99\cdot 10!} = \frac{1}{3592512} \sim 2.7835675983824134\times10^{-7}
\end{align}
$$
So up to 6 decimal places,

$$\cosh 1 \sim 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \frac{1}{6!} + \frac{1}{8!} = \frac{6913}{4480} \sim \color{red}{1.543080}357142857$$

Comment: I don't say that I disagree, however, the question is $cosh(1)$ correct to six decimal places is 1.543081 of we round up the answer. Can you please take a look over my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342729/round-to-n-decimal-places?noredirect=1#comment9062900_4342729

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify cosh 1 to
$$
cosh(1) = 1/2 (1/e+e^1)
$$
And use the following approximation of e (good for 9 decimal digits):
$$
\frac{271\,801}{99\,990}
$$
Alternatively you can approximate e yourself using the series:
$$
e=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\dots
$$
You will only have to develop the series for a few steps until the first significant digits will not change any more.

Comment: Minor nitpick: on the first sentence, $\cosh 1$ **is** $\frac 1 2 (e+e^{-1})$, so maybe the word "simplify" is not appropriate.

Comment: I would suggest the words identity and evaluated

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the Taylor series, try using the taylor series for $\cosh$ which is:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Then you can expand the summation and you will have something like the following:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!} \ldots$$

Then you can simply sub in "$1$" for $x$ and you will have your approximation.

Comment: `\sum` gives a $\sum$ that admits super- and subscripts at the natural places.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Fixed!